# Separating autocomplete jquery page

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I've made autocomplete function from jquery. I've tested and it's working fine except the loading when open the page is too long. so I want to make one file again that this page can be opened more quickly or reloaded faster.

This is the autocomplete file

```
<?php
include "../config/config.php";
$region = $_GET['region'];
?>
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
 <?php
     $sql=mysql_query("SELECT country_name FROM country WHERE region='$region' ORDER BY country_name");

     while($f=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
     {
        echo " '".$f['country_name']."', ";
     }
 ?>

];
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#tags" )
  // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
  .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
  .autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
    },
    focus: function() {
      // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
  });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label >Type country: </label>
<input id="tags" size="50">
</div>
```

How I separate this file into two file using ajax and sql ?

Comment: I don't get it, what you want to do? You want append script from external file, run script after page is fully loaded or what?

Comment: @Sojtin Yeah, I want to create php file that separated from jquery, so I think a reload page will be faster

Answer (score 0):

Put your PHP in a seperate file for example named "getRegions.php"

```
<?php
     include "../config/config.php";
     $region = $_GET['term']; //this has to be changed to "term" !!!!

     $sql=mysql_query("SELECT country_name FROM country WHERE region='$region' ORDER BY country_name");

     $regions = array();    
     while($f=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
     {
        $regions[] = $f['country_name'];
     }

     echo json_encode($regions);
```

And then instead of using `var availableTags` in your javascript portion, change in `.ajax()` the [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) attribute to `source: 'getRegions.php'`.

That should do the trick!